# Simple average over a block of a fixed size

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to use it to process some spectral data. My data is arranged row-wise with each spectra for a given sample in a separate column. The data looks like this:

```
   Plant  Spec1  Spec2  Spec3  Spec4  Spec5  Spec6  Spec7  Spec8  Spec9 Spec10 Spec11 
1  samp1 0.0422 0.0475 0.0453 0.0426 0.0472 0.0527 0.0498 0.0424 0.0423 0.0434 0.0463
```

I have many plant samples(`samp1` to `samp10000`) and about *2000 spec#* readings. I would like to calculate a simple average over blocks of 5 spec readings per each sample (`spec1 to spec 5`, then `spec6 to spec10`), i.e. average every 5 column readings per individual row.

I thought of transposing the data, however I subsequently have to normalize the *5-block simple averaged data* by dividing each 5-block average by the mean spectral readings (spec1-spec2000) per each plant sample.

Any suggestions as to how I may proceed with the coding for R?

Comment: Hi Kurt, you will get more help if you show that you've tried to solve this yourself, so please include a sample of the code you're using along with an indication of why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach that's pretty straightforward.

First, some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- cbind(Plant = letters[1:5],
           as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 12)))
x
#   Plant         V1         V2         V3          V4          V5          V6
# 1     a -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 -0.04493361  0.91897737 -0.05612874
# 2     b  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432 -0.01619026  0.78213630 -0.15579551
# 3     c -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406  0.94383621  0.07456498 -1.47075238
# 4     d  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999  0.82122120 -1.98935170 -0.47815006
# 5     e  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309  0.59390132  0.61982575  0.41794156
#            V7         V8         V9        V10        V11        V12
# 1  1.35867955 -0.4149946 -0.1645236 -0.7074952  0.3981059  1.9803999
# 2 -0.10278773 -0.3942900 -0.2533617  0.3645820 -0.6120264 -0.3672215
# 3  0.38767161 -0.0593134  0.6969634  0.7685329  0.3411197 -1.0441346
# 4 -0.05380504  1.1000254  0.5566632 -0.1123462 -1.1293631  0.5697196
# 5 -1.37705956  0.7631757 -0.6887557  0.8811077  1.4330237 -0.1350546
```

Second, figure out the column "groups". Use `gl` to create column groups:

```
myBreaks <- gl(ceiling((ncol(x)-1)/5), 5)[1:(ncol(x)-1)]
```

We can make use of this information in `sapply`, and we can conveniently use `rowMeans` to get the values you're looking for.

```
cbind(x[1], 
      sapply(levels(myBreaks), function(y) {
        rowMeans(x[-1][myBreaks == y])
      }))
#   Plant           1             2          3
# 1     a  0.18778055  0.0031074991  1.1892529
# 2     b  0.36537233 -0.1083305812 -0.4896239
# 3     c  0.05997134  0.0646204262 -0.3515075
# 4     d -0.24235365  0.2024774526 -0.2798217
# 5     e  0.47255547 -0.0007180433  0.6489845
```

Comment: Thanks a million Ananda, this worked very well. However I am running into problems when I try to find the average per row. However I think I managed to solve it by using  xx.T <- as.data.table(xx)
           > xx.T[,list(Mean=rowMeans(.SD)), by=Plant]

Comment: New problem: After calculating the mean of each row, I would like normalize the data per row, by dividing each element in a row, by the row's mean. I tried to use   < xx.T/rowMeans(xx.T) >. But I get the error <code> "Error in rowMeans(xx.T) : 'x' must be numeric.
"

Comment: @user2507608, your original question said nothing about use of the `data.table` package. Please update accordingly. Also, it seems like your problem in your second comment would be that you are trying to take `rowMeans` over a column that includes character variables (like the first "Plant" column).